# Tiny MCE Editor cursor is pointer not text

Tags: php, html, css, tinymce

In my Tiny MCE Editor, the cursor is pointer when hovered which should be in text. I'm not getting any method or way to change cursor to text when hover on MCE Editor. The documentation of Editor is also not giving any idea.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes. I m using bootstrap

Comment: it is most likely interfering, probably the modal box. Maybe my answer here will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836103/textbox-not-clickable-in-tinymce-modal-box/26880625#26880625

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with a blank `<textarea>`, you will only get text cursor on very top line. It's something I dislike about TinyMCE.

Comment: Have you tried setting CSS for that?

Comment: @EternalHour I looked over your answer but it is same, that is cursor is pointer not text other than first line or filled lines.

Comment: I think you'll need a fiddle to show the problem.

Comment: @EternalHour my editor is behaving same as your's which you have shown in JSFIDDLE demo. But my requirement is to change the cursor: text all over the editor area not a cursor: pointer. When we focus on editor where no text is wriiten, the cursor is pointer which I want is text. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add one more option in tinymce init function

```
setup : function(ed) {
                  ed.on("click", function() {
                      ed.focus();
                  });
              }
```

now your code will like this

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    width: '100%',
    plugins: ["advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor","searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
              "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste textcolor"
              ],
    toolbar: " bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on("click", function() {
            ed.focus();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello the cursor changes on hover of the body element of the tinymce. So i figured this option on init:

```
content_style: "body { min-height: 225px;}"
```

change the size of the min height based on your tinymce window height.